# How to get data of author of Facebook group post with API v3+

Tags: facebook

We have a Facebook app using the v3.1 API. We like to give our users the option to retrieve the posts from the groups that they manage. However, it seems the new API severely limits this: you can only retrieve posts from a public group. But even worse: it seems you cannot retrieve the name and avatar of the author anymore, judging from the Facebook Graph Explorer:

[image]

I'm hoping there is something I'm overlooking. Does anyone know of a way to get the author's data with the v3+ API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But even worse: it seems you cannot retrieve the name and avatar of
>   the author anymore, judging from the Facebook Graph Explorer:

This seems to be limitations of the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/). As per the document, **unless author of the post grants permission to your application**, you cannot get it.

> Limitations
>
> By default, personally identifiable information will not be included in API responses. For example, when requesting the content's of a post, the response will not include the name of the member who created the post.
>
> In order to have a group member's default User fields included in API
>   responses when available, the member must grant your app the
>   groups_access_member_info permission. This permission can be granted
>   through Facebook Login or through the Groups UI. For information about
>   how to use the UI to grant permission, see Allow or remove access to
>   group apps in the Help Center.

However, the document doesn't specify any limitations on retrieving group posts so as long as you app is installed for the group, you should be able to retrieve all posts from the group.

> **Requirements In order to use this API:**
>
> Your app must go through the App Review process.
>
> A group member must install your app on the group.

Comment: Thanks, Dipen, for the comprehensive and definitive answer. It seems I should have read the documentation better. :)